# How do I handle empty lists in nested for loops?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I am looking for a way to iterate through the product of two lists that can sometimes be empty.
I was going to use itertools.product for that, so it would look like this:

```
import itertools

list1 = [1, 2]
list2 = ['a', 'b']

for i, j in itertools.product(list1, list2):
    print(i, j)
```

We would get:

```
1 a
1 b
2 a
2 b
```

And that's what I expect. But when one of the lists is empty, the loop won't print anything:

```
list1 = [1, 2]
list2 = []
    
for i, j in itertools.product(list1, list2):
    print(i, j)
```

Whereas I would like it to behave as if there was just one list. So, using itertools, do the equivalent of:

```
for i in itertools.product(list1):
    print(i)
```

which would have returned:

```
(1,)
(2,)
```

I could put this into a long if statement, but I am looking for a simple tweak that would easily scale if the number of lists increased. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well a product with zero equals zero, so what is happening makes sense. What do you expect to get as `j` if list2 is empty?

Comment: I was hoping it would work as if there was just one list - so, keeping the itertools.product, perform the equivalent of:
for i in itertools.product(list1): print(i)

Comment: I have updated the question to emphasize what I am hoping to get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put them in one variable and filter them to use only the non-empty ones:

```
import itertools

lists = [1, 2], []

for i in itertools.product(*filter(bool, lists)):
    print(i)
```

Or if having them in separate variables is truly what you want:

```
import itertools

list1 = [1, 2]
list2 = []

for i in itertools.product(*filter(bool, (list1, list2))):
    print(i)
```

Output of both:

```
(1,)
(2,)
```

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing it would be checking if any of the lists is empty and putting in some value, but this is not the most elegant solution. For example:

```
import itertools

list1 = [1, 2]
list2 = []

if len(list2) == 0:
    list2.append("")

for i, j in itertools.product(list1, list2):
    print(i, j)
```